# В чем разница между Iterable и Iterator?

Tags: java

Если мы хотим использовать итератор, то обычно, как в случае с коллекциями, мы имплементируем этим классом `Iterable`. А зачем тогда интерфейс `Iterator`? Это не получается "масло масленное"? Если объект `Iterable`, то и методы все соответсвующие будут. А зачем еще `Iterator`, как отдельный интерфейс?

Comment: Объект другой. коллекция перечисляемого типа (Iterable), а перечисляет ее перечислятор (Iterator)